# Stack two UIImages to one

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm searching for a way to stack two `UIImages`. I don't want to simply merge them (add one above another), i rather want to stack their pixel values.
My knowledge ends by getting the data by `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`, but that's not the point. I would need raw image data of both images and create a third image with stacked data.
I really appreciate any help here. :/

Edit:
I've talked with a colleague of mine and he noted, that this is something like the screen layer-property in photoshop. Maybe that clarifies what i mean.

Comment: by "stack their pixel values", you mean just lay one right on top of the other, no opacity stuff, right?

Comment: No, i mean literally to add them toghether.

Comment: Like go pixel by pixel and add the RGB values of pixels from both image together? Couldn't you just do this by layering them one on top of the other and setting the top one at .5 alpha? If you want them both combined in one UIImage you can still follow the steps below to do that.

Comment: What's the difference between “stack” and “merge”, and how is either of them different from addition?

Comment: Sry, i tried to name sth. which i don't know what it's called. Maybe they are all the same, but i think i stated quite clear that i want to achieve something like the screen layer-property in photoshop.

Comment: adding pixels like that would just make bright images. are you looking for frame averaging?

Comment: That's exactly what i want, bright images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fake long exposure on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019549/fake-long-exposure-on-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using the same method as fake a long exposure.

[fake long exposure @ stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019549/fake-long-exposure-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you are asking, you can do this by arranging the images how you would like them in a UIView, and then taking a "screenshot" of the UIView and saving it to a UIImage.

1. Put both UIImages in UIImageViews with `UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];`. Make sure to do that for all of the images you want to combine.
2. Make a UIView with the size that you want the final image to have: `UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight)];`
3. Set the frames of both UIImageViews to be where you want them in the final image. You can also
   set the opacity here. `myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);`, `myImageView.alpha = .5';`
4. Add both UIImageViews to the UIView you created. `[myView addSubview:myImageView];`
5. Now you need to take a screenshot of the UIView. I don't know if it actually needs to be visible on screen for this to work. You can try it both ways. If it does need to be visible, it probably won't matter as it will be on screen for less time that you can measure. Take the screenshot and store it to a UIImage with the following code (for some reason I could not get it to format properly):

   `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.myView.bounds.size);`
   `[self.myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`
   `UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`
   `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`

You will also need to add the line `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to the top of your class if you don't want any warnings.

There, your combined UIImages are stored in `finalImage`. Hope this helps, tell me if this wasn't what you were asking for.

Comment: oh this wasn't what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bitmap for each of the images by using something like:

```
pixels = CGBitmapContextGetData( ctx );
```

once you have the pixels, you can add them in any way you want.  You can do a plain sum, an average, or ...

If your pixmap is RGBA, then the pixel at location n will be

```
p = ((UInt32 *) pixels)[n];
```

To iterate through all the pixels:

```
pixelCount = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(ctx)/4 * CGBitmapContextGetHeight(ctx);
for (i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
   p = ((UInt32 *) pixels)[n];
   newpixel = processpixel(p);
   copyofpixels[n] = newpixel;
}
```

(note above that you can not change pixels data, I believe it is immutable.  You have to write to a copy or a new array, and then later create a UIImage from that bitmap, using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);`)

This is how you can access the pixel data:

```
redByte = p & 0x000000ff;
greenByte = p & 0x0000ff00 >> 8;
blueByte = p & 0x00ff0000 >> 16; 
alphaByte = p & 0xff000000 >> 24;
```

When adding, make sure you add the reds, greens, blues, and alphas separately.  If the added value is more than 255, then cap it at 255.  Depending on your use, ignore alphas.  For example:

```
reds = redByte1 + redByte2;
if (reds > 255) reds = 255;
greens = greenByte1 + greenByte2;
if (greens > 255) greens = 255;
blues = blueByte1 + blueByte2;
if (blues > 255) blues = 255;
// as you can see, everything is getting brighter.  A red dot and another darker red dot will result in a brighter red dot, and not a color in-between.
```

And to set it back to the pixel:

```
UInt32 *newPixel = reds + (greens << 8) + (blues << 16); // put in an alpha here if you want
copyofpixels[n] = newPixel;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds great!  
Looks like exactly what i needed. I'll try it at the weekened.

Comment: If you run into problems, post here. Playing with images at the pixel level is fun. Not easy though.

Comment: Ok, i'm stuck. How can i iterate through the pixels array? I mean, how do i get its lenght?

Comment: added info on `CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(ctx), CGBitmapContextGetHeight(ctx)`