# Fake long exposure on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, core-graphics, avfoundation

I have to implement long exposure photo capabilities to an app. Since i know that this is not really possible i have to fake it. It should work like "Slow Shutter" or "Magic Shutter".

Sadly i got no clue how to achieve this. I know how to take images with the camera (through `AVFoundation`) but i'm stuck at merging them to fake long shutter times.

Possibly i need to manipulate and combine all the images with `coregraphics` but i'm not sure about this (even the how). Maybe there's a better solution to this.

I would appreciate every help i can get here,
thank you people!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try the [plus lighter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCGBlendModePlusLighter) blend mode.

Comment: Sound like what i need. I'll test it tomorrow! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose it would be possible to average together the results of several shots.  I've mucked around a bit with the core graphics stuff to resize images (averaging together adjacent pixels), but with lower res images.  The algorithm I used is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052188/high-quality-scaling-of-uiimage/6064453#6064453) -- maybe it'll give you some ideas.

There may, of course, be a better way, and some tricks for working efficiently with high-res images.  Can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the images to pixel bitmaps.  Align and stack the bitmaps.  Then try applying various 3D convolution filters to the 3D pixel array.

Comment: may it be possible for you to explain that?